# Можно как-то изменить названия столбцов в QTableWidget c++? не просто на текст а на переменную? Вот код

Tags: c++, qtablewidget

```
char a='b';
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList()<<a);
```

Comment: Вы все правильно делаете, только переменная `a` должна быть правильного типа:   `QString a="b"` .

Comment: QStringList()<<QString(a)